# Phonegap / iOS : How to add an App to the native sharing window

Tags: ios, cordova

my need seems very common but I'm not able to find how to do it with iOS. 
So I guess I'm not looking for the right name. (On Android it's called webintent).

The idea is to add my app into the native sharing windows on iOS, especially on the "Camera roll".

Like the other apps in the green rectangle in the example bellow,

[screenshot example](http://cl.ly/image/3Z3y2r3t0H0u)

Does anyone knows where I need to look ?

Thanks,

Comment: you can use this plugin for social sharing https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: I read and read again this plugin README but it doesn't seems to do what I'm looking for.
I don't want to share a content from my app to another, but from the native photo library into my app.
Like in my screenshot

Comment: The answer is in fact that it's a new feature of iOS8 : http://www.imore.com/sharing-ios-8-explained